# Why won't my Canon Powershot take a photo when the flash is on?

Tags: canon, flash, powershot, settings

I have a Canon Powershot SD4500 IS. It takes photos normally when flash is set to off, or when it’s light enough in Auto mode for it not to be necessary, but the camera will **not** take a photo when the flash is set to on or when it is dark on Auto mode. I click the button, and a red light comes on, but no photo gets taken/no noise is made. The battery is close to full and I’ve messed with lots of settings. Any recommendations??

Answer (score 2):

The simplest advice is "wait".  Between the time the camera is certain it needs the flash and the time it can take a shot, it needs to charge the flash capacitor.  If that time ends up indefinitely long, it may be that the charge circuit or, more likely, the flash capacitor itself is hosed.  The latter is kind of a certainty if you can hear occasional popping noises.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to manual focus.

If it is dark and the camera cannot confirm focus it will not trigger the shutter (depending on settings).

Comment: It's an Ixus (very low-end P&S). [Specs don't mention a manual focus mode](https://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/dcc595.html).